# Updating table data in optimal manner

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am getting twitter data by my query at every 3 hours. One of the field `url` is key here. For each url I have `retweet_count` value.

Sometimes in next 3 hour I get similar url records as previous. But `retweet_count` comes with updated new value.

In each query I am gettong about >200 urls.

One way is during each insert I check whether that `url` exist or not. If not then insert directly. If already exist then fetch previous `rt_count` value and compare with newer, if different then update it.

Gradually my data will grow to lacks of record in table. Where above case will take too much delay.

Is there any better way to do this? any optimistic solution for this?

```
$insertQuery2 = "INSERT INTO frrole_article_sentiment (`url`, `sentiment`, `title` , `time` , `img_url` , `rt_count` , `tweet_count`, `today`, `youtube_url`, `hash`) VALUES ('".$url."','".$sentiment."','".$title."','".$time."','".$img_url."','".$rt_count."','".$tweet_count."','".$today."', '".$is_youtube."', '".$hash."')";

                    if (!mysqli_query($con,$insertQuery2))

                    {

                        //die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));

                    }
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Is this true: Once every 3 hours you are executing a MySQL query and the result set has at least 2 fields: `URL` and `retweet_count`? _(If this is true, share the query)_ Then 3 hrs later you run the same query and sometimes the same `URL` field is returned but with a different `retweet_count` value. You want to insert into **frrole_article_sentiment** when the row in result set you just queried has a `URL` value that is not in **frrole_article_sentiment**. If that `URL` value is there, then update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using MySQL, you can use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` feature:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Your query will become something like:

```
INSERT INTO frrole_article_sentiment (url, rt_count)
VALUES('$url', '$rt_count')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rt_count=$rt_count;
```

("url" assumed to be PK, query shortened for simplicity, you should include all the fields)

Comment: thanks, will this insert update existing `url` and `rt_count` too ?

Comment: It will insert the record is there is no "url" duplicate, otherwise it will just update the rt_count value, but see the documentation on mysql.com for full reference